# Definite pitch designs only, what musical instrument and class of musical instruments would be easiest to design if the world reset?

Tags: science-based, technology, physics, music

I saw a couple other threads with slightly similar questions. But I want to stress with this one, that the focus is what instrument and instrument family would be the easiest to build anywhere in the world if we started from the beginning of human civilization again. Also, definite pitch capable designs only! Even if it’s only capable of one pitch at a time.

Comment: This is "yes you're very clever" answer:  The easiest musical instrument is the one we all carry wherever we go: the voice.  Singing ftw

Comment: @JamesK ah no! Nice try! But I don’t think we know who designed the voice but we can’t design it ourselves lol! It is the best instrument though!

Comment: [Hambone](https://youtu.be/m9kaQ3ZKPE0?si=nf9M7slzwakUG4rq)

Comment: What could be easier than a drum?

We all know a half-way sophisticated drum has a skin over a sounding body - and do we not also all know that's a later development and at its simplest, a 'drum' need be no more than a lump of wood - though of course preferably, a hollow lump? Beyond that, doesn't the subject descend into vocabulary?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin “Definite pitch” designs tho. I guess now I’m just trying to understand which wooden instruments are pitch capable and easy to design considering metal ones are typically harder to design and more modern (handpan etc). As you mentioned though some skin over wood designs are definite pitch, I’ve found a couple others like the wooden slit drum.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin What could be easier than a drum? Claves.

Comment: @biziclop You could be right and d'you believe most non-musicians would consider claves to be instruments? I'm not sure either about that, or whether any definition should be set by musicians or just anyone…

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Fair point, it depends on the context. In a way, anything that makes a sound you can influence is an instrument. Like when I was a kid, I loved to "play" on an egg slicer. To me it was an instrument. The reason I mentioned claves specifically was that the question asked for "definite pitch capable designs only", which for me has put it into a more musician-like context.

Comment: @biziclop Quite and while your ideas seem wholly reasonable, Lecifer's Question seems without useful research or even opinion… Oops!

Answer (score 17):

End-blown flutes are very easy to construct from readily available materials.

You only need a reed or other hollow-stemmed woody plant, with some way of cutting and shaping it (stone tools will suffice.)  You can either make a set of pan pipes, with the different lengths forming different pitches, or make finger holes to create something like the North African/Middle Eastern *Ney*.

Transverse flutes and fipple flutes are also easy to design, and were made (for example from bones of large birds) in prehistoric times.

Comment: Or as in the case of didgeridoo, you use solid wood but let termites do most of the hollowing out work.

Comment: This is why they have kids play the [recorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recorder_(musical_instrument)) in schools (spawning a series of memes). It's cheap and indestructible: you can buy a _Yamaha_ recorder for under $10.

Comment: That you can get a recorder for $10 is a miracle of civilization.  Think how long it would take you to make one from scratch (I mean really from scratch, no metal tools, unless you first make the metal)

Answer (score 12):

**Flutes and Drums**

Flutes are the oldest known instruments in the archaeological record. Some date back up to around 50,000 years old! Also, it's argued that Neanderthals made
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paleolithic_flute
It's also thought that a prehistoric flute can be attributed to neanderthals though this is debated.
https://www.nms.si/en/collections/highlights/343-Neanderthal-flute

No pitch but drums have probably been around for similar periods of time, in the form of skins stretched over stuff and banged, but these soft materials don't preserve through time in the archaeological record so we can only speculate.

Comment: Re, "no pitch, but drums..." Wha'd'y'mean, "no pitch?" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PRTxPJfCKhY&t=30s _Most_ drums have some discernable pitch. I would argue that whether or not a thing "rings" with some discernable pitch when we hit it, and the purity of the tone if it rings at all, is a pretty good test to decide whether we should call the thing a "drum" or a "bell" or neither of the above.

Comment: Also, just in case you think that it's unfair of me to cite classical tympani, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4NEnwLn2V1A&t=54s

Comment: @Nosajimiki instruments that are monophonic or polyphonic

Comment: @Nosajimiki wait when you say variable pitch what do you mean? I know some people believe an instrument such as hi hat has a “definite pitch”, but I think they do differ in comparison to instruments with the proper harmonic series for “definite pitch”.

Comment: The trouble with drums isn't that they don't have pitch (they very much do) but that ones that can be **reliably** tuned to a definite pitch are a lot more difficult to construct.

Comment: @biziclop You are describing  specific pitch, definite pitch just means that it makes a single pitch noise instead of multiple overlapping pitches.

Comment: @Nosajimiki Ah, okay. English isn't the language I've learnt my musical terms in, so just to be clear are you saying is that a tom is a definite but not necessarily specific pitch instrument, while a tuned bell (where the fundamental/overtone difference isn't very clear) is specific but not definite?

Answer (score 7):

[Pan Pipes/Flutes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan_flute)

[image: Andean Pan Flute]

or [Wood Chimes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tubular_bells)

[image: Wood Chimes]

They can be made with a number of naturally grown hollow plants.  Materials available all over the world, require minimal tools to construct, and require no complex assembly.  You don't even need to space or cut complex holes for multiple notes, just trim to length to tune.

Comment: Random question. But are steel drums, tongue drums, handpans, & uh singing bowls are fairly all difficult to craft in comparison to these?

Comment: Those all have multiple tones in one object, with tuning done by bending the metal,  (note: require sheet metal) .  If you manufacture one tuned section incorrectly you've often broken the whole instrument.  If you mess up one chime it only messes up that one.  Much simpler to tune and manufacture.

Comment: Ahh gotcha makes sense

Comment: @Lecifer The biggest obstacle to all those is always going to be the metal. Humans have only had metalwork (copper, then bronze) for the last 7000 years, and that entirely depended on the luck of having suitable ores around. (South America and Australia never had ore available, so didn't have metalwork until Europeans arrived.) You then also need flat metal sheets; making that much metal and having it available for frivolous purposes instead of for tools and weapons pushes your date still later.

Comment: @Lecifer, drum-scale metal sheets only date back to about 600 BC for bronze, and 1200 AD for steel.

Comment: @Mark Sheet metal dates back to the early copper age (about 4000BC), sheet iron/steel to about 1000BC.  The dates you are citing are for plate armor specifically.  Just because you can turn metal into a sheet does not mean it will make a suitable armor material which is why plate armor came so much later than the actual invention of sheet metals.

Comment: @Nosajimiki, there's sheets, and then there's big sheets.  It's a lot easier to make a palm-sized piece of sheet metal than it is to make a drum-sized piece.  And drums *need* to be made from single-piece sheets -- any sort of join (welded, riveted, or otherwise) will destroy the sound.  I used plate armor as point of comparison because that also needs large single-piece sheets of metal.

Comment: @Mark Large copper bowls and embossed sculptures were common in ancient Sumer over 5000 years ago, and copper tools & weapons made from large unwelded sheets was common up to 6000 years ago.  The prevalence of scale and chain armor before plate armor was not because they did not know how to make the shapes, it was because the metal itself was so malleable that if struck in combat, the joints would deform and lock up.  Scale and chain armor offers much more flexibility, ventilation, and protection of joints than plate which is vital to pre-medieval infantry-centric warfare.

Answer (score 4):

#### Literally Everything Less Electric

Pitched Percussion. This is simple! If your world is Post-Pockyclyptic, then you've got loads of already existing metal, stone and wood bars around. You just need to harvest, shape to the desired form and carve down or add mass to tune. Add some carved sticks and connecting strings and you've got a carillon.

Even if your setting is naked humans dropped off on a new planet, it only takes very basic skills to shape bone, wood, stone and leather into fully functional and well tuned xo-phones.

A hollowed log, a piece of prepared skin and some ropes are enough to make a tunable drum! Metalwork can get you nakers and timpani.

Bamboo, long hollow bird bones, clay, hollowed wood all make the basis for wind instruments. With very basic metallurgy you can fashion simple system flutes, clarinets, oboes and cornetts. The better your woodworking skills, the bigger the instruments you can make.

But really, anyone can make a well tuned whistle or flute or shawm from a piece of pipe and a reed.

Wood and horn and some basic techniques can yield you a pibgorn, a cornett, an oliphant; add some leather for bagpipes and the like.

A smallish log can give you the basis for a dulcimer, a harp, or a zither. You've got many string choices from gut to silk to other plant fibres. Add a little metallurgy for brass strings! As your woodworking improves, you can thin the walls of the instrument body and make any stringed instrument that exists now.

Even keyboard instruments are not beyond reach! You won't be able to make a modern piano until you get cast iron and steel, but harpsichords, clavichords, regals, organs, harmoniums, wheelharps are all within reach once you've got carpentry skills and some decent tools.

Comment: Very interesting! I find the periods when different instruments are designed odd. Like the handpan (hang), tongue drum, & steel pan are all supposedly modern designs. But not that they couldn’t have been made back then, or is there construction actually more difficult than I think? I know singing bowls were being crafted 5000 years ago. Or also like a tabla or some other pitched membranophone.

Comment: @Lecifer --- Yep! Handpan / Hang is less than 25 years old or so. Steel drums are only just about 100 years old. The 55 gallon drum was patented in 1905, so there's your basic terminus ante quem. I'd not be surprised if people were banging on them as early as 1905, but the instrument in question dates to the 1930s. I would concede that a steel drum could have been invented as early as the late 1700s with the introduction of rolled steel. I don't think other metals would work well if at all.

Comment: It just blows my mind that they’re  modern designs! I want to look more into how they’re designed. Pitched percussion is my favorite, especially polyphonic designs. One would think they aren’t as difficult to design as string instruments and complex woodwinds/brass, but maybe that’s not the case.

Comment: @Lecifer --- You might be interested in these, made from brass and aluminium: https://guda-drum.com/guda-coin-brass

Comment: @Lecifer More like 3500 years. Which is still a long time ago, but consider that' difference is the difference between present-day and the fall of Rome. :)  Metalwork is way harder than you think, and way more dependent on the luck of whether you've got copper and tin resources anywhere near you. Far more likely than a tongue drum would be a kalimba, but even there you need good quality spring-grade metal, not simply a cast or wrought arrowhead.

Comment: @Graham I’m assuming but same goes for Singing Bowls (Metal) too? Singing Bowls are my personal favorite lol.  What about Crystal Singing bowls for example. Im sure that material would be hard to come by as well. I don’t know much about design but I’m going to get into it at some point. Also tuning forks, very interesting designs.

Comment: @elemtilas very cool!!!

Comment: "anyone can make a well tuned whistle or flute or shawm from a piece of pipe and a reed"  Getting the shape of the mouthpiece right to create an actual whistling sound is harder than you may think.  I think most people could figure it out eventually, yes, but it takes a fare amount of trial and error to figure it out, especially if you don't have youtube or an existing instrument to use as a prototype.

Comment: @Nosajimiki --- Making it *perfect*, like a high quality professionally made musical instrument, yeah, I'd agree with you. I don't think the OP is trying to reinvent the Yamaha factory here. And as someone who has made these kinds of instruments, it really is not that hard to do!

Comment: @elemtilas no, I mean making it whistle at all.   I remember being a teenager trying to make a bamboo flute, and if you don't get the air flow and angles just right, it does not make a sound at all.  I did not have all the internet resources back then to explain how a flute creates a noise or how a flute is supposed to be made; so, I was shooting in the dark, and after several failed attempts I gave up.  People who hand make flutes for a living already know the mechanics of the airflow, angles needed, etc.  But if you don't know, it takes a lot of trial and error to figure out.

Comment: @Nosajimiki --- And yet people have been making whistles and flutes for myriads of years, all without professional training, science, or written resources. And without the benefit of civilisation. YMMV, but in general terms, these things aren't hard to make. Literally, boys and girls (but boys especially) were generally expected to be able to make these kinds of things in their preteen years in decades and centuries past.

Comment: @elemtilas What you are citing is people who come from 1000s of years of wood whittling tradition with fathers teaching sons thier everything they know.  But, the OP here says the world has been reset.  I take this to mean that the humans are having to figure it out with no foreknowledge of how to do it.

Comment: @Nosajimiki --- I'm just citing normal people. I didn't come from some long line of famous whittlers and it really doesn't take a whole lot of skill to make these things! Whatever. Honestly, I don't think this line of discussion is bearing any fruit. If you want to address this particular topic, please write it in your own answer!

Answer (score 3):

For a percussion instrument with definite pitches, try a xylophone.

The difficult part is simply to carve a suitable piece of wood so that it makes the desired note when struck. Once you have a set of these pieces of wood, you can place them on straw to create a *strohfiedel*.

Answer (score 2):

See the Wikipedia article on the [Chelys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chelys). This was an early form of lyre. A myth (there are many variations) had it that Hermes found the dried corpse of a tortoise that had dried in the sun, leaving seven fibres stretched across the shell. That does not explain how the lyre got its extended neck, but once you have the basic idea, the rest follows.

Another possibility if resetting the world left lots of scrap metal is the [Mbira](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbira) or Thumb Piano. Africa had these for thousands of years. They can use wood instead of metal.

Answer (score 2):

One more instrumen I can think of is the Kalimba or its close relative the Mbira.

A series of metallic spikes of different lengths generate different pitches when plucked or striken. A wooden box would serve as a resonator and metallic spikes are scraped from older artefacts. How far the civilization is "reset" can determine how adept this civilization would be in processing the metal ores and from what sources. On the other hand, wooden spikes, presumably bamboo, have been used for the task as well. See the history of the tool here [[source]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbira)

Answer (score 1):

I understand that stringed instruments have already been suggested, but this answer aims to specify a motivation for them, though speculatively at best.

If the world reset, I'd wager that hunting would be important again and I would assume that bow and arrow designs would be developed rather quickly.

Of course this depends on how much history and folklore is available. But it's easy to see that different sized bows, custom made for different hunters or for different purposes, would make different sounds when the strings are plucked.

Assuming further that a good hunt, and given that cooperative hunting is much simpler and lower effort than farming for small, clan like pockets of humanity, leads to leisure time ( personally I think our common intuitions about modern society and the role of farming are short sighted ). I'd also guess that variations on bows to make different sounds would be considered.

Animal calls and bird songs are natural and serve to inspire curiosity and creativity in humans. So it's not a big stretch to imagine stringed instrument abstractions, along with the sounds that we hear in sea shells, and so on.

All simply ripe for the fertile mind to play with.

Comment: On why I think our intuitions about farming are short sighted, consider what happened when Europeans came to north America. They killed off a lot of the game because that was the quickest and easiest thing to do. They already had farming, but they plowed the rich soil long _after_ it became less viable to get a large haul hunting for meat. Its a simple matter of lowest hanging fruit, so to speak. I.e. we ended up farming because we didn't have a better option. Necessity is the mother of invention and all that. I don't think it's more sophisticated than that.

Comment: Well said and theorized! It seems to be simple designs for each instrument type. But as far as the easiest well defined pitched instrument type, it is probably strings. Either those or wooden aerophones. Surprisingly, drums seem to be the be the most difficult as far as pitched designs go as the really good ones require tons of metal and other materials (as covered above). Oh, along with brass instruments. Which again, require a lot of metal and intricate shaping.

Comment: To be fair, there are challenges for each. We have to learn braiding and knots to know about string, tanning to know about hides, carving and fire working to make wooden bowls. Metal comes much later, probably after farming is developed and the need arises to make more kinds of tools and defenses. I recommend the book Clan of the Cave Bear by Jean Auel if you haven't checked that one out. She covers a lot of ground theoretically and actually put a lot of research into her world which she uses to hypothesize the transition from matriarchal to patriarchal deity.

Comment: Tangentially, this made me start to wonder about multi-millennia cycles of humanity, but the more I think about it, the more I have to consider that ideological evolution is as much a result of circumstances as is evolution over time. When the world is big, we have no choice but to cooperate. When the world becomes too small, we'll have no choice again but to cooperate. ;-)

Comment: @Lecifer Excluding drums, do you know what orchestral instrument has remained unchanged since the Middle Ages? It's the trombone. No, I don't think Early man had trombones. My money would be on a plucked string. Early bone flutes survive, but you have to know where to drill the holes. You can tune a plucked string with tension. or with finger stopping.

Answer (score 1):

Slit drums produce different pitches when struck at different points. Lots of hollow/semi-hollow logs occur naturally that work as slit drums; deliberate construction is just a tiny step from that.

Answer (score 0):

### Clap Sticks

[image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clapstick#/media/File:Didgeridu_and_clap_sticks.jpg]

Sure, pipes, flutes, ocarina, drums, etc. are going to be pretty easy to makes once you get past your basic survival needs, but they still require time and tools to make, and in those first few years when every hour spent crafting must be spent in the name of survival needs, setting aside the time to make even a simple flute will be a luxury not worth taking.  However, there is one common tribal instrument that takes no effort at all to make: clap sticks.

All you need to do is pick up two sticks and knock them together.  At most, you will need to spend 5 minutes scraping off any excess shoots and bark.  When you clap them closer to your hands, they make a higher pitch sound, and when you clap them closer to the ends they make a lower pitch sound; so, they are not specific pitched instruments, but the pitch a good clap stick makes is definite.

Also, unlike most other instruments, you don't need to finish it to use it.  Over time, you can refine your clap sticks in small incremental steps.  You may at first start off just taking any sticks from your nightly firewood pile.  Over time the sticks that make more definitely pitched sounds get kept and the less-definitely pitched sticks are returned to the your firewood pile.  So before long, you will have some nice, straight, dry, knotless hardwood sticks pulled aside for your nightly jam sessions without having to invest any real work into making your instrument.

#### Clarifying Definite Pitch

Since this is not a common term outside of music theory, I believe there is some confusion about what this means. Definite pitch means that a sound follows a wave pattern that is all more or less one pitch like a key on a xylophone.  An indefinite pitch is like the sound of a tambourine or rattle where the sound it makes is a wide range of simultaneous pitches.

Tuned/tunable instruments are called specific pitch instruments, but there are also a wide range of unspecific, definite pitched instruments which includes most slapsticks, hand drums, etc.

Instruments that are not both specific and definite pitch are often called unpitched instruments.  But Google does not seem to know the difference; so, when you look up if certain instruments are indefinite pitch, you will often get answers for unpitched instruments instead; so, if you Google clap sticks, the results you get can be very misleading.

This said, slapsticks can be either pitched or unpitched based on thier design and use.  If they are straight and made out of an aged homogenous wood like oak, they will be pitched.  If they are bent, tapered, greenwood, or made out of a stick with distinct heartwood and sapwood like hickory, then it will make an less pitched sound. The technique you use can also make a difference between if you get a definite or indefinite pitched sound out of them much like how a drummer can get either a definite or indefinite pitched sound out of a djembe, though generally speaking, the term definite pitched instrument just means that it CAN make a pitched sound, not that it always will.

Comment: These aren't definite pitch instruments.

Comment: @elemtilas definite pitch is not the same as absolute pitch.  I've revised my answer to better explain the difference and why slapsticks are (or atleast can be) definite pitch instruments.

Comment: If they're tuned, then they would be definite pitch instruments!  I appreciate your edits. A definite pitch instrument is one that is tuned to a specific note or pitch --- like tympani, celeste, xylophone, etc. While that doesn't take any more skill than making a whistle, it is a little more than just rubbing off the bark! I'd agree with you: if you take a piece of wood, rub off the bark and then tune it to a specific pitch, and then take another piece of wood and do the same, you'd have a specific pitch set of clapsticks.

Comment: @elemtilas A **specific** pitch instrument is one that is tuned to a specific note or pitch.  A definite pitch instrument is one that makes a sound in a narrow set of audiowave lengths. Like I said, you have to be careful Googling this one because when you look up definite pitch, you get a lot of sources for pitched.